# Vue реактивность , двухстороннее связывание

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Есть 2 массива :

```
data: {
        b: [
          [3,3],
          [4,4]
        ],
        a: [1,2],
           result:[],
        },
```

Нужно что бы получилось :

```
[
  [3,3,1],
  [3,3,2],
  [4,4,1],
  [4,4,2]
]
```

Из-за связывания я так понял получается:

```
[
  [3,3,1,2],
  [3,3,1,2],
  [4,4,1,2],
  [4,4,1,2]
]
```

Как с этим бороться ? 
[Ссылка на JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/463637xv/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С Vue 
никогда не работал, но в вашем JS Fiddle подправил немного обработчик клика и получил нужный масив...

```js
let workBox = new Vue({
  el: "#workBoxesApp",
  data: {
    b: [
      [3, 3],
      [4, 4]
    ],
    a: [1, 2],
    result: [],
  },
  methods: {
    click: function() {
      let tmpArr = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < this.b.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < this.a.length; j++) {
          let tmpB = this.b[i].slice();
          tmpB.push(this.a[j]);
          tmpArr.push(tmpB);
        }
      }
      this.result = tmpArr;
    },
  }
});
```